# Java Nashorn store Function

Tags: javascript, java, java-8, nashorn

I have a custom functional interface

```
public interface ThingFunction {
    Object apply(Thing thing, String... flags);
}
```

I currently have a method of storing them for later use

```
public class Thing {
    private static Map<String, ThingFunction> functions = new HashMap<>();

    ...

    public static void addFunction(String key, ThingFunction function) {
        functions.put(key, function);
    }

    ...

    public Object executeFunction(String key, String... flags) {
        return functions.get(key).accept(this, flags);
    }

    ...
}
```

I'm trying to expose these functions through a JS API (using the Nashorn engine).  Basically, I want the user to be able to write a javascript function like `function(thing, flags) {...}` and have it be stored as a ThingFunction in the functions map.

I know I can case the engine to an `Invocable` and use the `Invocable::getInteface(Class)` to create a ThingFunction from javascript code

```
...
engine.eval("function apply(actor, flags) {return 'There are ' + flags.length + ' arguments';}");
Invocable invocable = (Invocable) enging;
ThingFunction function = invocable.getInterface(ThingFunction.class);
function.apply(thing, "this", "is", "a", "test");
...
```

However, this approach means I can only have one `apply` method in the engine.  Is there a way I can make many functions and store them in a map as shown above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nashorn allows passing a script function as an argument for any Java method that requires a single-abstract-method (SAM) interface type object. Since your ThingFunction is a SAM interface, you can do something like this:

File: Main.java

```
import javax.script.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ScriptEngineManager m = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine e = m.getEngineByName("nashorn");
        e.eval(new FileReader(args[0])); 
        Thing th = new Thing();
        // script evaluated is expected to 'register' func, foo
        // call those functions from java
        th.executeFunction("func", "arg1", "arg2");
        th.executeFunction("foo", "bar", "j");
    }
}
```

File: main.js

```
var Thing = Java.type("Thing");

// register two functions with Thing.
// Nashorn auto-converts a script function to an object
// implementing any SAM interface (ThingFunction in this case)

Thing.addFunction("func", function(thing, args) {
    print("in func");
    for each (var i in args) print(i);
});

Thing.addFunction("foo", function(thing, args) {
    print("in foo");
    for each (var i in args) print(i);
});
```

To compile and run, you can use the following commands:

```
javac *.java
java Main main.js
```

Another approach (which is Nashorn independent and would work with older Rhino jsr-223 engine as well) is to use Invocable.getInterface(Object, Class) [ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/Invocable.html#getInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Class%29 ]

In your script you'd define multiple objects - each having a script function property called "apply". And you can create one ThingFunction instance on top of each such script object. Evaluated script would look like

```
var obj1 = { apply: function(thing, args)  { ... } };
var obj2 = { apply: function(thing, args)  { ....} };
```

From the Java code, you'd do something like:

```
 Object obj1 = e.get("obj1");
 Object obj2 = e.get("obj2");
 ThingFunction tf1 = invocable.getInterface(obj1, ThingFunction.class);
 ThingFunction tf2 = invocable.getInterface(obj2, ThingFunction.class);
```

Comment: That is a *superb* answer.  I'll try it out and let you know if I have any troubles.

Would you recommend either of the two ways over the other?  I'm leaning towards the first, but I have next to no Nashorn experience.

Comment: Works like a dream.  Thanks a million :)

Comment: If you're going to use jdk8+ and nashorn, I'd recommend the first approach.